# Show Google Maps V2 markers based on selected tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager

I'm using `Fragments` and `ViewPager` to show two tabs inside my app. There's a map inside the main activity:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          tools:layout="@layout/activity_map"
          />
```

I would like to show different set of markers on map in each tab. First tab is loading them from local db and the second one from the remote server. I've tried placing the logic inside `onCreateView` in `Fragment` but they both get called immediately when the activity starts, not when one of them is selected, so markers aren't replaced on tab select. How should I proceed?